# Problems Downloading PDF FIle with okhttp3 and retrofit

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

My android application consume a service that returns a PDF file that contains certain data of the user, the problem is that when the service takes more than 5 seconds without responding the connection closes but the request is still open so new connections are made and then a timeout exception is launched.

if the response takes less than 5 seconds everything is ok.

this is a capture of the petition observed with charles made in the app.
[image: charles capture]

I'm using okhttp3 and retrofit. this is how i build the client

```
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .authenticator(tokenAuthenticator)
            .addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor(dataProvider))
```

I think the problem is about sockets or something but i cant find anything about it.